# WebJob Dependency Injection Binding to Generic Class

Tags: c#, generics, azure-webjobs

I had a series of classes that I used to process WebJobs that looked something like this:

```
public class EnvelopeSalutationJob : BatchJob
{
    public EnvelopeSalutationJob( StringWriter swLogger )
        : base( swLogger, "Envelope Salutation Job" )
    {
    }

    [ Singleton() ]
    public async Task ProcessMessage(
        [ QueueTrigger( "%" + nameof( ContainerQueueConstants.EnvelopeSalutation ) + "%" ) ] EnvelopeSalutationMessage msg,
        TextWriter azureLogWriter
    )
    {
        PhaseNames.SetNames( "Processing Homes", "Job Completed" );

        await ExecuteFromMessage( msg, azureLogWriter, Launch );
    }
}
```

These worked great using AutoFac as a DI framework, with a configuration that looked like this:

```
public static class ContainerConfig
{
    public static IContainer GetContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // per job
        builder.RegisterType<StringWriter>();

        // jobs
        builder.RegisterType<EnvelopeSalutationJob>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

But recently I wanted to "genericize" the jobs, so that they were not tied to specific DbContexts. I tried to use a pattern like this:

```
public class EnvelopeSalutationJob<TContext, TUser>
    : BatchJob<TContext, TUser>
    where TContext : IdentityDbContext<TUser>, ICampaignContext, new()
    where TUser : IdentityUser, INamedUser
{
    public EnvelopeSalutationJob( StringWriter swLogger )
        : base( swLogger, "Envelope Salutation Job" )
    {
    }
    [ Singleton() ]
    public async Task ProcessMessage(
        [ QueueTrigger( "%" + nameof( ContainerQueueConstants.EnvelopeSalutation ) + "%" ) ] EnvelopeSalutationMessage msg,
        TextWriter azureLogWriter
    )
    {
        PhaseNames.SetNames( "Processing Homes", "Job Completed" );

        await ExecuteFromMessage( msg, azureLogWriter, Launch );
    }
}
```

The AutoFac configuration is changed to:

```
public static class ContainerConfig
{
    public static IContainer GetContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // per job
        builder.RegisterType<StringWriter>();

        // jobs
        builder.RegisterType<EnvelopeSalutationJob<ConnellJobContext, ConnellUser>>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The WebJobs console app starts up fine, but it complains:

> No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods
>   public.

Is it not possible to bind jobs to instances of generic classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I have tested this issue on my side and I could reproduce this issue as follows:
[image]

After I checked [Azure WebJobs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk) source code on git, I found that [DefaultTypeLocator.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Indexers/DefaultTypeLocator.cs) would use `IsJobClass` that invoking [Type.ContainsGenericParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.containsgenericparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to filter types as follows:

```
public static bool IsJobClass(Type type)
{
    if (type == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return type.IsClass
        // For C# static keyword classes, IsAbstract and IsSealed both return true. Include C# static keyword
        // classes but not C# abstract keyword classes.
        && (!type.IsAbstract || type.IsSealed)
        // We only consider public top-level classes as job classes. IsPublic returns false for nested classes,
        // regardless of visibility modifiers. 
        && type.IsPublic
        && !type.ContainsGenericParameters;
}
```

Also, [FunctionIndexer.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Indexers/FunctionIndexer.cs) would use `IsJobMethod` to filter methods as follows:

```
public bool IsJobMethod(MethodInfo method)
{
    if (method.ContainsGenericParameters)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (method.GetCustomAttributesData().Any(HasJobAttribute))
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (method.GetParameters().Length == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (method.GetParameters().Any(p => p.GetCustomAttributesData().Any(HasJobAttribute)))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Based on my understanding, Azure WebJobs SDK doesn't support you to bind jobs to instances of generic classes currently. You could define your `BaseDbContext` and leverage constructor dependency Injection to init your `DbContext` instance. Also, you could add your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites).